# Application_Start vs serviceAutoStartProviders

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I am using IIS7.5 to force my web app to load automatically (`startMode="AlwaysRunning"`), and I now want to preload my cache data. I am a bit confused though because two approaches seem identical:

1. use `Application_Start` in global.asax
2. use `serviceAutoStartProviders` in IIS config files

They seem rather redundant and doing the same thing. If they are, I guess I would rather use `Application_Start` than create code dependencies in IIS configuration files. Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Application_Start` in the global.asax is fired when the application receives it's first request (first user or autostart) so it is not used to start the site.

Use `serviceAutoStartProviders` to start
http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4#0.2__Toc253429241

The IIS Application Warm-Up Module is easier to use
http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

Comment: Well, that is what confuses me, usually it takes a first request to launch a site and thus cause Application_Start. Doesn't it happen automatically when `serviceAutoStartEnabled="true"`? I don't understand how can `serviceAutoStartProviders` happen without `Application_Start` happening shortly before or after.

Comment: The autostart sends a fake request to start the website, this will trigger the Application_Start. You can set an `initializationPage` to call a different page when starting.

Comment: To explain it a bit more, if `serviceAutoStartProviders` run but `Application_Start` does not until the first request, that means that in auto-start code there is no web application context yet, thus `HttpContext` is not initialized, which means there is no global Cache object to use for cached data. Yet there is. So it implies that context is alive, which means app is alive, which means that `Application_Start` must have happened.

Comment: D'oh, ok, you are right, its actually not intended for my purpose at all -> docs on `serviceAutoStartProviders ` -> "This interface is intended primarily for use by WCF applications that are non-HTTP applications. ASP.NET developers who want to preload ASP.NET Web applications should use the simulated HTTP requests in IIS 7.0 combined with the Application_Start method in the Global.asax file."

Comment: I got confused by Scott's blog post: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series

Comment: The IIS warm up module is the easier way to do this. http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

Comment: I'll try to get them to upgrade to Win2012/IIS8, but for now I have to contend with 7.5 (Windows 2008r2) on which the prod system runs.

Comment: The IIS application warm up module should be available from IIS 7.5 and higher

Comment: Its available as external module. Thanks.