# Where does ASP.NET server start code go?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a new ASP.NET Web Application project, using the "Empty" setting. This means I wasn't given any classes, and a fairly bare Web.config file. What file or config settings will I need to change to get a static class method to run when I first start the program?

[image]

Note: I tried adding a Startup.cs class with constructor, but that did not work, and I tried adding the `<appSettings>` tag with the child `<add>` tag specifying owin appStartup, but that did not work either.

Comment: Using the "Empty" template implies that you know enough about what you are doing to start with no scaffolding. Try using another template that creates the startup features for you.

Comment: I would like to get to the point where I know what I'm doing. I don't want a template because the most I will have is a single WebSocket server available down the line, but I want some logic to run even before someone first hits the websocket endpoint.

Comment: I would really appreciate an answer if you know what I need to do.

Comment: I suggest creating a project based on one of the other templates so you can analyze how to put it together.

Comment: It looks like I was looking to actually create a WCF service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very easy way to go about this, without needing to learn complicated IIS configuration, is to self host using ASP.NET Core.

First, install .NET Core: https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows

Second, instead of following their steps to create a new console app, follow these command line instructions:

1. Create a directory for your project `mkdir MyProject`
2. Enter into that directory `cd MyProject`
3. Create a blank ASP.NET core app `dotnet new web`
4. Run it `dotnet run`

This will create and run a new blank ASP.NET web application which you can visit at http://localhost:5000

Two classes will have been generated: `Program.cs` and `Startup.cs`. `Startup.cs` will contain the logic for handling requests and serving responses, while `Program.cs` will contain the `Main` and `BuildWebHost` methods.

**The server start code goes in the static `Main` method**, allowing you to initialize anything you might want before the web server is even initialized.

An added bonus of using .NET Core is that you can run this not only on just Windows, but also all *nix systems as well (Linux, MacOSX).

Answer (score 0):

It all starts with the global.asax. The IIS pipeline compiles global.asax, which usually references a global.asax.cs, which inherits from an HttpApplication. The application is then instantiated by the pipeline and its event handlers are called as pipeline events occur. The thing that sets everything off is the construction and Application_Start event of that application, where you compose the object graph, register bundles and routes, etc.

There is a lot more to it of course but that is where it all starts, if you want to try to reconstruct a working site yourself.

Comment: Global.asax Application_Start is only run once the first request is made. I would like something to run as soon as the server is started, so I can create some shared memory structures which can be accessed between all the different requests and is initialized potentially before any requests are ever made.

Comment: You can use application warmup or a startup provider.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559553/application-start-vs-serviceautostartproviders).

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for! Although seeing all the steps involved I will likely go with OWIN and avoid using IIS altogether.